# Localstorage: Count how many values in key when using stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

How can I count how many different values I have in 1 localstorage key.

For example:

This is my localstorage:

```
[{"id":"item-1","icon":"google.com"},{"id":"item-2","icon":"youtube.com"}]
```

For this example I'd like an alert of 2 different values. So basically I want to count the `{}`..

Is that possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`localStorage` is an object, so just `localStorage.length` gives you the number of entries.

However I think I might be misunderstanding you. Do you mean you have one key, and that key's value is a `JSON.stringify`'d object? If so, you could do `JSON.parse(localStorage.keyname).length` to unserialise the value and count how many there are in there.

Comment: Basically I have 1 key which will have many values as shown above. On my question, the key has 2 values.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for: JSON.parse(localStorage.result).length Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your object is saved as an array so just using the .length should give you the number of {} pairs you have. Try this (replace "whatever" with the name of your array:

```
var something = localstorage.whatever[];
var length = something.length;
alert("length = " + length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the number of items in the key for you

```
testing = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEYNAMEHERE));

//Lets count how many we have back
obj = eval('(' + testing + ')');

//And the total is...
objCount=0;
for(_obj in obj) objCount++;

alert(objCount)
```

Comment: If you've run JSON.parse you don't need to also run eval. Also, this will count array prototype elements like length itself, and all its methods.