# LocalStroage: Count number of items in local storage and display it in UI using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of products and i'm storing it in my `LocalStorage`. My LocalStroage looks something like this:

```
{
"2":{"id":"2","colour":"Black","size":"S","quantity":"1"},
"3":{"id":"3","colour":"Blue","size":"Universal","quantity":"1"},
}
```

I want to display '2' in my UI(because i have two items in my LocalStorage). What I tried so far is:

```
 var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage["productTable"]);
        for(var i in temp) {
            totalitems ++;
        }
        itemsincart.innerHTML = '<i class=\"ion-android-cart\"></i><span id=\"cart-total\">'+totalitems+'</span>';
```

In this i'm getting `totalitems` as sum of `id` which I know is wrong.

And tried this [Localstorage: Count how many values in key when using stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093625/localstorage-count-how-many-values-in-key-when-using-stringify) and in this i'm getting '1' everytime.

Can anyone please help me figure out how I can show the number of items in my LocalStorage?

Comment: How many items are you assuming in your current example ?

Comment: in this example, only 2, but it shall increment or decrement depending upon the number of items user will add to his cart.

Comment: Where have you declared and initialized `totalitems`? Can you add a log for `temp` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use for loop `Object.keys(temp).length` to get the length of json object like following snippet:

```js
var temp = {
"2":{"id":"2","colour":"Black","size":"S","quantity":"1"},
"3":{"id":"3","colour":"Blue","size":"Universal","quantity":"1"},
};
console.log(Object.keys(temp).length+" items in cart");
```

In your case try following:

```
var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage["productTable"]);
itemsincart.innerHTML = '<i class=\"ion-android-cart\"></i><span id=\"cart-total\">'+Object.keys(temp).length+'</span>';
```

Comment: just one more question: when i refresh the page the number of items is not visible, but when i add a product it's visible. how can i show the number of items when we refresh the page?

Comment: When you refresh your page you have to maintain your data in localStorage. How you do it ? Please go through [How to keep localStorage values after refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564795/how-to-keep-localstorage-values-after-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

I recently searched a solution for this, and found out the easiest way is just to create another localStorage item (cartQty).

So everytime you add a product to your cart, increase the cartQty number.

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
  //...
  ++i;
  window.localStorage.setItem('cartQty', i);
  // display your cart quantity
  $('span#total').text(window.localStorage.getItem('cartQty');
}
```

- didn't realised question is for AngularJS, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
var totalitems = JSON.parse(localStorage["productTable"]).length; 
itemsincart.innerHTML = '<i class=\"ion-android-cart\"></i><span id=\"cart-total\">'+totalitems+'</span>';
```